# REGEX ignorando un caracter?

Tags: regex, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Estoy trabajando en una base de datos bastante larga y para evitar revisar fila por fila estoy utilizando REGEX para encontrar patrones y reemplazarlos, sin embargo surgió algo extraño, todas las filas incluyen un patron similar a este

```
(digito)(digito).-(palabra o palabras)_
```

por ejemplo:

```
13.-POLEAS DE RANURA_FABRICACION_6.3/8 4RB BUJE INTERCAMBIABLE A 1.5/8 CUÑERO 3/8 FIERRO
```

```
10.-JAULAS Y PISTAS_BERLISS_93548(1X1.3/8X2)
```

```
1.-BANDAS_1040-8M-25
```

Quiero extraer todo lo que esté antes del primer guión bajo ( _ ) pero sin incluirlo e intenté usar esto:

```
^.+?(?=_)
```

El problema es que en lugar de usar el primer guión bajo, usa el último es decir, por ejemplo en:

```
13.-POLEAS DE RANURA_FABRICACION_6.3/8 4RB BUJE INTERCAMBIABLE A 1.5/8 CUÑERO 3/8 FIERRO
```

En lugar de obtener:

```
13.-POLEAS DE RANURA
```

obtengo:

```
13.-POLEAS DE RANURA_FABRICACION
```

¿Que sucede?

Comment: Había escrito una respuesta mal pero estaba mal. ¿Estás seguro de que con esa expresión regular no te da el resultado correcto? Acabo de probarlo en la misma consola del Chrome y `str.match(/^.+?(?=_)/)` me devuelve "13.-POLEAS DE RANURA" para la cadena de tu ejemplo.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so] ¿Por qué has incluido  [tag:google-hoja-de-cálculo]? ¿vas a usar la expresión regular en una fórmula? De ser así ¿cuál es la fórmula que vas a usar?

Comment: De hecho @juanrpozo creo que tu respuesta está bien, usé ^([^_]*) como expresión REGEX y ahora sí tomó todo hasta el primer guion bajo sin incluirlo en la busqueda.

Comment: La formula que estaba intentando hacer era comparar parte de una celda con otra que contaba con una categoría. Esta es la que me resultó que me parece fue la respuesta de @juanrpozo =SI(REGEXEXTRACT(D2,"^([^_]*)")=S2,VERDADERO(),FALSO())

Comment: (/^\d+.-[A-Za-z0-9\s]*/)  recorriendo palabra solo como letras/numero y espacio

Answer (score 1):

Podrías utilizar:

1. La siguiente expresión regular: Hace un match de cualquier caracter desde 1 hasta veces ilimitadas, es decir, que haya una o más coincidencias hasta el caracter '_'.

```
^(.+?)_
```

2. En este caso sería similar al anterior.

```
^(.*)_
```

Esto genera 2 partes:

- Un grupo 1: que contiene toda la cadena desde el primer caracter
  hasta la primera coincidencia de guión bajo sin incluirlo.
- Un full march: que contiene toda la cadena desde el primer caracter
  hasta la primera coincidencia de guión bajo incluyéndolo.

Podrías combinar ambas con una parte de tu regex, por ejemplo:

```
(.*)(?=_)
```

De esta forma el full match ya se hace hasta la primera coincidencia ya que la siguiente coincidencia no la captura "?=".

Comment: ¿Has probado las expresiones regulares que propones en la hoja de cálculo de Google? Pregunto porque la la pregunta incluye [tag:google-hoja-de-cálculo]

Comment: Hola! porque estoy utilizando REGEX en la busqueda y reemplazo dentro de Google Sheets :)